# How can I make this toggle javascript buttons (images) less clumsy?

Tags: javascript, button, toggle

I'm looking to see if there's a way to make this code less clumsy?  I'm thinking there must be a more elegant way to make 2 buttons that toggle between 2 or more button states on hover and click.

Thanks!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">

    img1 = "images/buy1.png"; 
    img2 = "images/buy2.png"; 
    function chng(c_img) { 
    if (c_img.src.indexOf(img1)!= -1) c_img.src = img2; 
    else c_img.src = img1; 
    }  
    img3 = "images/sell1.png"; 
    img4 = "images/sell2.png"; 
    function chng2(c_img) { 
    if (c_img.src.indexOf(img3)!= -1) c_img.src = img4; 
    else c_img.src = img3; 
    } 
    </script>

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="sell">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/buy1.png" onclick="chng(this)" name="img" width="115"
      border="0" height="50" id="img" /></a>
    </div><a href="#"><img src="images/sell1.png" onclick="chng2(this)" name="img2"
    width="115" border="0" height="50" id="img2" /></a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect fit for using CSS background sprites. Create images that have both states in them, stacked vertically:

```
----------------------
|      "on" image    |
----------------------
----------------------
|     "off" image    |
----------------------
```

Give your links a class and apply the images to them to the elements using the [`background-image`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image) property (using the shorthand notation below):

```html
<a href="#" class="buy1"></a>
```

```css
.buy1 {
   display: block;
   width: 115px;
   height: 50px;
   background: transparent url(images/buy1.png) left bottom no-repeat;
}

.buy1.on { background-position: left top; }
```

Then with the JavaScript, you can simply toggle the class:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sell a").on('click',function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('on');
    });
});
```

This approach has a number of advantages:

- Fewer server requests (you can combine all the images into one sprite
  sheet and they will load in one request) mean better performance
- There will be no lag on hover as the "on" state is already loaded
- Much easier to maintain

**Edit** I'd add, you should put some real content in the links to give screenreader users something to navigate with. I'd typically use an image replacement technique for that:

```
<a href="#" class="buy1"><span>Buy Now</span></a>
```

```css
.buy1 span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: -10000px;
    left: -10000px;
    font-size: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Combine this with toggle-event to toggle on and off

Comment: @mplungjan unless I'm missing something, there's no need to add `toggle()`, `toggleClass()` will toggle the styling on each click and shift the image to the desired appearance.

Comment: Assuming the user wants to only change appearance, but if it is an add and remove from shopping basket then a little more is needed in my opinion

Comment: @mplungjan, ahh, I see where you're going with that. I figured that there would be an ajax call to update the cart (that was not included in the OP code).

Answer (score 1):

Using [jQuery toggle-event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

**NOTE**

The code will handle any link and image where the ID of the link and the image has some kind of match - doable with `data` as well but compatible with non-html5 browsers too. 
You will have to provide images or classnames for each different image but the toggle script is fixed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var icons = {
        buy:{ 
          on:"http://ev9.evenue.net/evenue/linkID=global-fargo/images/buy-tickets.png", 
         off:"http://ev8.evenue.net/evenue/linkID=global-sandler/images/buyTickets.png"
        },
        sell:{ 
          on:"http://ev9.evenue.net/evenue/linkID=global-fargo/images/buy-tickets.png", 
         off:"http://ev8.evenue.net/evenue/linkID=global-sandler/images/buyTickets.png"
        }
    } 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".toggleLink").toggle(
          function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $("#"+id+"Img").attr("src",icons[id].on);
            // OR change the className of the link 
            // OR use data-toggle - but no need to test the image src
          },
          function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $("#"+id+"Img").attr("src",icons[id].off);
          }
        );
    });
    </script>

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="sell">
      <a href="#" id="buy" class="toggleLink"><img src="http://ev8.evenue.net/evenue/linkID=global-sandler/images/buyTickets.png"  id="buyImg" width="115"
      border="0" height="50" /></a>
      <a href="#" id="sell" class="toggleLink"><img src="http://ev8.evenue.net/evenue/linkID=global-sandler/images/buyTickets.png"  id="sellImg" width="115"
      border="0" height="50" /></a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE** Using data attributes to prove a point

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".toggleLink").toggle(
          function() {
            var img = $(this).find("img");
            img.attr("src",img.data('toggleon'));
          },
          function() {
            var img = $(this).find("img");
            img.attr("src",img.data('toggleoff'));
          }
        );
    });
    </script>

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="buy">
      <a href="#" class="toggleLink"><img src="images/buy1.png" 
      data-toggleon="images/buy1.png" 
      data-toggleoff="images/buy2.png"  
      width="115" border="0" height="50" id="img" /></a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: Have a look here for a great version

[Element with hover then click removes hover effect and click again adds hover again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7899318/295783) with a [fiddle by Greg Pettit](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7Tgwc/)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS selectors - like what is documented here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: Please read this too http://w3fools.com/ - better resource: [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/hover.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you mean more stylish there is way by css or jquery

http://www.webreference.com/programming/css_stylish/index.html

http://speckyboy.com/2009/05/27/22-css-button-styling-tutorials-and-techniques/

Answer (score 0):

It seems fine. I can think of a more elegant way, using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

First off, give each one of your elements the `toggleImg` class. Then, give each button the attributes `data-toggleon` and `data-toggleoff`. Remove the `id` and `name` if you desire.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".toggleImg").on('click',function(){
      if($(this).attr('src')==$(this).data('toggleon')){
       $(this).attr('src',$(this).data('toggleoff'))
      }else{
       $(this).attr('src',$(this).data('toggleon'))
      }
    });

    });
    </script>

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="sell">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/buy1.png" class=toggleImg data-toggleon="images/buy1.png" data-toggleoff="images/buy2.png"  width="115" border="0" height="50" /></a>
    </div><a href="#"><img src="images/sell1.png" class=toggleImg data-toggleon="images/sell1.png" data-toggleoff="images/sell2.png" width="115" border="0" height="50"  /></a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code can be thus easily extended--you can just add new `img`s wherever you want with the appropirate class/attributes and not worry about adding new JS.

Comment: If you take the approach of storing the alternate images in the markup, don't make up bogus attributes but rather use the compliant `data-` attribute (`data-toggleon`)

Comment: @steveax: Aah yes (HTML5/jQuery newbie here). I've seen that before. Thanks!

Comment: Not to mention [toggle-event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) is likely created to handle this kind of issue in the first place

Comment: @mplungjan: That defeats the point of my code--then you have to use a new JS snippet for each element. I prefer keeping JS and HTML separate. Of course, lambdas would be a way to bypass this.

Comment: See my answer. Only one event defined and no JS in the html at all

Comment: @mplungjan: Not exactly what I meant--I really prefer the extendable method where you can add new stuff by modifying only one scrap of code. In yours, you have to do it twice--add more JS and add more HTML. But that's just my opinion of good code :)

Comment: Not to continue this discussion in someone else's answer, but what part of the code I provided do you have to modify twice? The code I gave will handle any link and image where the ID of the link and the image has some kind of match - doable with data too but compatible with non-html5 browsers too. Of course you have to provide images or classnames for each different image

Comment: @mplungjan: Basically I'm saying that you have to add a new element to `icons` _as well as_ adding new HTML. No biggie. And yes, I guess there is the HTML5 issue as well (though I'm quite sure that `attr()` works for those even if `data()` may not)

Comment: @mplungjan: awesome, +1. you didn't have to do that, though it was a matter of personal opinion :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10381/discussion-between-mplungjan-and-manishearth)